# Ignoring touch events on UIView except for the Buttons on them.

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, touch, subview, touch-event

I have a MainViewController(A) and another DetailedViewController(B) as its subview. In "B" I have a UIView containing some UIControls like a UIButton, UILabel and some UIViews.

I need to ignore all the touch events within this UIView except for Button clicks and I have to remove the subView if clicked outside the UIView.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

A option might be to set a custom view in the detail view controller.
In that view you can override the hittest function.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *resultView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (![resultView isKindClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        resultView = nil;
    }

    return resultView;
}
```

Touches not on the buttons will than be ignored. But if you have a scroll view under it and you will start dragging on the buttons the scrollview will be ignored.